# (android) an scrollview that gets programmatically filled loses title

Tags: android, layout

I have this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/play"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:text="@string/highScores"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"></View>


            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I fill the 'container' TableLayout with elements like this:

```
    layout.addView(buildTitleRow());

    for (int i = 0; i < users.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject parent = (JSONObject) users.get(i);

        layout.addView(buildRowFrom(parent, i + 1));
    }
```

buildTitleRow:

```
private TableRow buildTitleRow(){

    TableRow result = new TableRow(this);

    int color = Color.parseColor("#ffff00");

    View view = new View(this);
    view.setMinimumWidth(10);
    result.addView(view);

    view = new View(this);
    view.setMinimumWidth(10);
    result.addView(view);

    //the same for other views        

    return result;
}
```

buildRowFrom:

```
private TableRow buildRowFrom(final JSONObject element, int counter) throws JSONException {

    TableRow result = new TableRow(this);

    String rowName = element.getString("name");

    int color = Color.parseColor("#00ff00");

    if(rowName.equals(userName)){
        color = Color.parseColor("#ffffff");
    }

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(counter + ".");
    textView.setTextColor(color);
    result.addView(textView);

    //some other views

    return result;
}
```

this really works well just until the scrolling needs to take place...

Once there are more elements than the height of the screen the table remains scrollable (luckily) but the original 'title' Textview doesn't show up anymore (you can't scroll up towards it anymore)

Does anyone know how to tweak the layout to keep it visible once more elements are added than the size of the screen?

Thanks a lot,

S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your code and found find something wrong in your xml layout.

The attribute `android:layout_gravity` will change the layout's own gravity. So if set this attribute to a `LinearLayout` with `center` and its `android:layout_height` is `wrap_content`(means that the real height of the 'LinearLayout' will exceed the screen's height) and fill `ScrollView`(its height is the screen's height) with it, the `LinearLayout` will align to center of its parent `ScrollView`.

If you want to keep the content of 'LinearLayout' centered, you can set `android:fillViewport="true"` to `ScrollView` and then the `LinearLayout` will fill the parent and you can use `android:gravity="center"` on the `LinearLayout`. [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport)

But there is still some thing need to be changed. In your java code, `View view = new View(this)` this line will new a `View` and then you add it into `TableLayout`. But this `TableLayout` will be full of `View` because of the description of `View` below.

`* The base class implementation of measure defaults to the background size,
* unless a larger size is allowed by the MeasureSpec. Subclasses should
* override {@link #onMeasure(int, int)} to provide better measurements of
* their content.`

You can use a concrete view like `TextView` instead of it.

I don't know if I have clarified it. I think if you remove the attribute `android:layout_gravity` of `LinearLayout`, it will work.

I'm glad if it would help.

Comment: It helps but if you remove that 'center' and the inner layout isn't bigger than the screen it is put above and not centered anymore (that's why I put that property), nice answer to build on however, I did a small adaptation to fit my needs (see answer below) and I now have the best layout I could dream of ;-) thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I just looked into this question and found something you might want to see.

Answer (score 0):

I did the adaptations Paul suggested + change android:layout_height of the ScrollView to "wrap_content" to keep the inner LinearLayout centered when the android:layout_gravity="center" was removed from it (see complete layout below).

I wouldn't have found it without Paul's suggestion and explanation so I'll accept his answer as answer, this answer is just for the sake of completeness...

I'm not expecting this question to get that much of attention anyways ;-)

Thanks Paul :-D

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/play"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:text="@string/highScores"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"></View>

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

            </TableLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```